# Adding key in class object dictionary when creating a subclass item- Python 3+

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a log in system for a bit of fun to practice my beginner's python skills and looking for a little bit of help.

This is the part of my code I am getting stuck on:

```
class Userbase(object):

    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.userbase = {}

    def getUBName(self):
        return self.name

    def changeUBName(self, newname):
        self.name = newname

    def resetUB(self):
        self.userbase = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ': ' + str(self.userbase)


class Username(Userbase):

    def __init__ (self, username, userbase):
        Userbase.__init__(self, userbase)
        self.username = username
        userbase[self.username] = []
```

My goal was to have a main class Userbase, where I can create a database of users simply as such:

```
dtb1 = Userbase('dtb1')
```

From there I had in mind to be able to create a user using the subclass Username, is there a way for me to make it so whenever a user is created as such:

```
p1 = Username('Jo', dtb1)
```

The user 'Jo' is directly added to the dictionary dtb1 such as:

```
print(dtb1)
>>> dtb1: {'Jo': []}
```

This might not be the best way to do it but using what I know this is what I came up with. Is it even possible? Your help would be much appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: Why is your Username class a subclass of your database class?  Is a username a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `Userbase` to contain multiple `Username`s. `Username` should not be a subclass of `Userbase`.

It is not an [i-sa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. A `Username` is not a special type of `Userbase`.

Try instead something like this.

```
class Username():

  def __init__ (self, username, userbase):
      self.username = username
      userbase.userbase[self.username] = self
```

Here `Username` adds itself to the `Userbase` passed in its constructor.

An even better approach is to add a method to `Userbase` that adds a `Username`.

```
class Userbase(object):

  ...       

  def add_user(self, user):
    self.userbase[user.username] = user
```

Now after creating a `Username` it can be added to the `Userbase`.

```
b = Userbase('my_base')
u = Username('bob')
b.add_user(u)
```